# How to make the division sign only occur once between numbers for basic calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, function, calculator

I want to have my calculator division sign to show only once between numbers, in other words I want the division sign to occur once no matter how many times I click the division button it should only occur once unless there is a number in between.

I want:81/9/3
Not: 3///3//333

Same goes to the multiplication sign below:

```
    function divide() {
        if (document.getElementById('btndiv').click = true) {
            document.getElementById('TextAreaResultspace').value += '/';
        }
    }
    function multiply(){
        if  (document.getElementById('btnx').click = true) {
            document.getElementById('TextAreaResultspace').value += '*';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? This code seems rather odd...

Comment: Just check if the last character is `/` before appending another `/`

Comment: How to do it Javascript wise?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle please : http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (symbol can be any character you want):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('TextAreaResultspace');
var val = elem.value.trim()
// add symbol only if last character of text input is not a symbol
if(val[val.length-1] != symbol){
    elem.value += symbol;
}
```

I trimed whitespaces so that you don't allow something like "3 /  /  /  3" either. Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9wzY/1/

Andrei

Update: how it works:

- elem variable gets assigned the object for the result.
- val variable gets assigned the current value of elem from which leading/trailing whitespace are removed (by calling trim method)
- val.length is the length of the text in val, but first character starts at position 0 so last character is at position val.length-1. Therefore, last character of val is val[val.length-1]
- if the last character in val is different of what you want to add, then it appends it to elem.value. Otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its exactly what I wanted.

Could you please explain in detail what you did?

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You could check to see if the last character of TextAreaResultspace is a control character and only add the symbol if not, perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
function divide() {
    if (document.getElementById('btndiv').click = true) {
        append_symbol('/');
    }
}

var append_symbol = function(symbol){
    var control_chars = ['*', '/', '-', '+']
    ,   elem = document.getElementById('TextAreaResultspace');
    // add symbol only if last character of text input is not a symbol
    if(control_chars.indexOf(elem.value[elem.value.length-1]) === -1){
        elem.value += symbol;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It should use elem.value instead of elem and "==" instead of !==, like:

    control_chars.indexOf(elem.value[elem.value.length-1]) == -1

Comment: Thank you, Rob. Also change elem.value.length instead of elem.length.